# What is actually getting changed when Bump Version is run?

Tags: git, release, git-flow

According to http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/:

```
$ git checkout -b release-1.2 develop
Switched to a new branch "release-1.2"
$ ./bump-version.sh 1.2
Files modified successfully, version bumped to 1.2.
$ git commit -a -m "Bumped version number to 1.2"
[release-1.2 74d9424] Bumped version number to 1.2
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

After creating a new branch and switching to it, we bump the version number. Here, 
bump-version.sh is a fictional shell script that changes some files in the working 
copy to reflect the new version. (This can of course be a manual change—the point 
being that some files change.) Then, the bumped version number is committed.
```

But haven't we already named the branch `release-1.2`, and I assume we would then tag master as `1.2` when we release, so what exactly is `./bump-version.sh 1.2` changing?

Thanks.

Comment: Dont have any clue what your shell script is doing. However you can delete the tag `git tag -d tag1`.  You need to check who is maintaining the shell script to know what exactly its doing.

Comment: How can anyone here guess or know what **your** shell script is doing? Do a `cat bump_version.sh` or `type bump_version.sh` depending on your platform and look at the code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about a local script that hasn't been posted

Comment: Hi guys, I you read the question fully you will see I am referring to a popular Github process (see the URL I posted) and the text in my comment includes the following: "After creating a new branch and switching to it, we bump the version number. Here, bump-version.sh is a fictional shell script that changes some files in the working copy to reflect the new version." So my question is this: what do they mean when they say "changes some files in the working copy to reflect the new version".\

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the script in that post is a fictional shell script. So it's just mean that you have to update your files to reflect the new version

> After creating a new branch and switching to it, we bump the version number. Here, bump-version.sh is a **fictional shell script** that changes some files in the working copy to reflect the new version. (This can of course be a manual change—the point being that some files change.) Then, the bumped version number is committed.

The files mentioned above means all files which have version number description on it. Could be readme.md file, or gradle files, or source code with version number hardcoded on it, or anything

The example of this file is [django/__init.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4a461d49c775331ed52418f007974d61be1e06b9/django/__init__.py) file in django repository. So for the next release (suppose they will number it 2.2.0), the file should become something like this

```
from django.utils.version import get_version

VERSION = (2, 2, 0, 'alpha', 0)

__version__ = get_version(VERSION)

...
```

EDIT:

related commit example: https://github.com/django/django/commit/92fad87958763a649c698cf28b99ec2c4a2fd109#diff-484b5b08de7d25a106a8855101e2423e

related issue discussion: https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/26